# Google Maps co-ordinates to JavaFX application

Tags: maps, javafx

I wonder how to get coordinates from Google Map to JavaFX application when click has 
occurred? Here is an example of code where I'm trying to invoke Java function:

'showCoordinates' from JavaScript 'click' handler:

```
public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {
public void showCoordinates(String coords)
{
    System.out.println("Coordinates: " + coords);
}

@Override public void start(Stage stage) 
{   
    final WebView webView = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("googlemap.html").toString());

    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<State>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState,     State newState) {
                    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                        window.setMember("java", new JavaFXApplication());
                    }
                }
            });  
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setCenter(webView);
    stage.setTitle("Google maps");
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,1000,700, Color.web("#666970"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Application.launch(args);
}
}

// googlemap.html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
        #map_canvas { height: 100%; background-color: #666970; }
    </style>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">            
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.75089, -73.93804);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                panControl: true,
                navigationControl: true,
                streetViewControl: false,
                backgroundColor: "#666970"
            };

            var map = new     google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);     
            document.map = map;

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        //java.showCoordinates(event.latLng); ???
    });
    map.setCenter(location);
}       
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

After some experiments I came to a simple timer based solution. The idea is that a timer function regularly polls the javascript document and parses the result.

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.3, 4.59 );
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 9,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
  mapTypeControl: true,
  navigationControl: true,
  streetViewControl: true,
  backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
};

document.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
document.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

document.updateJavaFX = function updateJavaFX() {
    document.currentCenter  = document.map.getCenter();
    document.currentBounds  = document.map.getBounds();
    document.currentHeading = document.map.getHeading();
    document.currentZoom    = document.map.getZoom();
}
```

When the updateJavaFX() function is called the document variables (currentCenter for the position) are filled.

In the JavaFX code the following part (this part is called within an AnimationTimer) is used to retrieve the current lat lon position of the map.

```
    if ((mMapAutoUpdate.get()) && (mLastNow < pNow - 10000000)) {
    mLastNow = pNow;
    mMapView.getEngine().executeScript("document.updateJavaFX()");
    JSObject jdoc = (JSObject) mMapView.getEngine().getDocument();
    if (jdoc != null) {
        try {
            JSObject ds = (JSObject) jdoc.getMember("currentCenter");
            String cc = ds.toString().trim();
            cc = cc.substring(1, cc.length() - 1);
            String[] ccs = cc.split(",");
            double newlat = Double.parseDouble(ccs[0].trim());
            double newlon = Double.parseDouble(ccs[1].trim());
            mCenterLat.set(newlat);
            mCenterLon.set(newlon);
            int zoom = (Integer) jdoc.getMember("currentZoom");
            mZoom.set(zoom);
        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
            String ds = (String) jdoc.getMember("currentCenter");
            String[] ccs = ds.trim().split(",");
            double newlon = Double.parseDouble(ccs[0].substring(4).trim());
            double newlat = Double.parseDouble(ccs[1].substring(4).trim());
            mCenterLat.set(newlat);
            mCenterLon.set(newlon);
            int zoom = (Integer) jdoc.getMember("currentZoom");
            mZoom.set(zoom);
        }
    }
}
```

I made a blog entry for a possible solution;

http://oldguardprogrammer.blogspot.nl/2013/01/javafx-and-google-maps.html